Upload and Create a table from a csv file in BigQuery
I have tried to create a table within a dataset that I already created and saved, the first csv file was uploaded successfully, but the second one I tried it shows the following error when I clicked the Create table:
Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 100; errors: 100. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
Looking at the details it shows many messages as the below:
Error while reading data, error message: Invalid time zone: AM; line_number: 2 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 15 column_index: 1 column_name: "Time" column_type: TIMESTAMP value: "4/1/2016 7:54:00 AM"
Error while reading data, error message: Invalid time zone: AM; line_number: 3 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 50 column_index: 1 column_name: "Time" column_type: TIMESTAMP value: "4/1/2016 7:54:05 AM"
Etc
How can I fixed those errors in the file? it is too big for Excel to open it...and I am very new with BigQuery and also R!
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

The timestamp values in your CSV (4/1/2016 7:54:00 AM) don't match the format expected by BigQuery. See Loading CSV data from Cloud Storage:

When you load JSON or CSV data, values in TIMESTAMP columns must use a dash (-) or slash (/) separator for the date portion of the timestamp, and the date must be in one of the following formats: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day) or YYYY/MM/DD (year/month/day). The hh:mm:ss (hour-minute-second) portion of the timestamp must use a colon (:) separator.

You need to generate your data using a timestamp format that BigQuery understands, or preprocess it before trying to load it into BigQuery.

Thanks a lot! but how can I preprocess my data (this would be change the date/time format to be TIMESTAMP format) if my file is too big to open in Excel? is there a way in csv or another programme where I can change it? sorry, very new and I am stuck on this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Post process might simplify stuff here (load data to BQ as String and use parse_timestamp to convert back)

@Eugenia24 if an answer helped you, StackOverflow etiquette is to upvote the answer :)

Couple of options

Instead of pre-process, go for post process

Change the column data type to String (after 1st load) → This let you upload the data seamlessly from 2nd load onwards
Create a view to convert back the string to timestamp using parse_timestamp function


Use LOAD DATA SQL with OVERWRITE option without giving any schema, so it creates a new table (similar to your 1st time loading of the table)
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#load_data_statement

